# Crashlytics Swift: Get fatalError() message to the crashlog

Tags: swift, crash, crashlytics, crash-dumps, crashlytics-beta

I have a number of `fatalError("Descriptive Error")` lines in my app. I'd like to find which line has actually triggered the error.

However, I can't get such an information with Crashlytics. Here's what I got:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10173cd24 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 128
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x101561118 _ArrayBuffer._checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds(_:wasNativeTypeChecked:) + 240
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x10157b318 Array.subscript.getter + 112
3  AppName                       0x10097d520 ClassName3.select(_:) (ClassName3.swift:61)
4  AppName                       0x1008ee03c ClassName2.init(_:) (ClassName2.swift:28)
5  AppName                       0x1008edca0 ClassName2.__allocating_init(_:) (ClassName2.swift:24)
6  AppName                       0x1008603c4 ClassName4.makeController() (ClassName4.swift:19)
7  AppName                       0x1008d6c88 ClassName.ClassName6(_:didSelect:) (ClassName.swift:108)
8  AppName                       0x1008d6e04 protocol witness for ClassName6Delegate.ClassName6(_:didSelect:) in conformance ClassName (<compiler-generated>)
9  AppName                       0x100855de0 ClassName6.text(card:) (ClassName6Item.swift:71)
10 AppName                       0x100855f04 protocol witness for ClassName5.text(card:) in conformance ClassName6 (<compiler-generated>)
11 AppName                       0x1007da8f4 ClassCell.buttonDidTap(_:) (ClassCell.swift:48)
12 AppName                       0x1007da958 @objc ClassCell.buttonDidTap(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
13 UIKit                          0x18d4826c8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
14 UIKit                          0x18d5a38a4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
15 UIKit                          0x18d48877c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
16 UIKit                          0x18d5be1dc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
17 UIKit                          0x18da63dd8 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 4340
18 UIKit                          0x18da60b50 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1236
19 UIKit                          0x18d4fb540 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404
20 UIKit                          0x18d4fb078 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 276
21 UIKit                          0x18d4fa8dc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3132
22 UIKit                          0x18d4f9238 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
23 UIKit                          0x18dcdac0c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2340
24 UIKit                          0x18dcdd1b8 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4744
25 UIKit                          0x18dcd6258 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1836fb404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1836fac2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1836f879c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
29 CoreFoundation                 0x183618da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
30 GraphicsServices               0x1855fb020 GSEventRunModal + 100
31 UIKit                          0x18d5f978c UIApplicationMain + 236
32 AppName                       0x1008925c0 main (AppDelegate.swift:13)
33 libdyld.dylib                  0x1830a9fc0 start +
```

4

Is there any way I can retrieve the message in `specialized _fatalErrorMessage(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 128` ?

Comment: What about all those `ClassName*.swift` errors you are getting? Are those not your project files?

Comment: The question is about how to get to the message inside a `fatalError` call. As it might have been parametrized, e.g. "The app crashed because of incorrect 2nd configuration parameter"